# Pass credentials in powershell Workflow

Tags: powershell, workflow

I have a powershell workflow to run on servers remotely but having issue to pass the credentials in workflow. The password should be from user at the time of execution.

```
workflow Gethost{
    param(
        [string[]]$Servers
    )
   $credential = (Get-Credential)
    foreach -parallel ($server in $Servers) {
        $session = inlineScript{New-PSSession -ComputerName $using:server -Credential $using:credential} 
        $id = $session.id
        inlineScript{Invoke-Command -ComputerName $using:server -Credential $using:credential -Filepath C:\Checkhost.ps1}
        inlineScript {Exit-PSSession}
        inlineScript{Remove-PSSession -id $using:id}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Get-Credential` cmdlet inside a PowerShell workflow. Only some limited set of cmdlets can be used inside a workflow. You can get the credential outside and pass that using  a parameter.

```
workflow Gethost{
    param(
        [string[]]$Servers,
        [PSCredential]$Credential
    )       
    foreach -parallel ($server in $Servers) {
    $session = inlineScript{New-PSSession -ComputerName $using:server -Credential $using:credential} 
    $id = $session.id
    inlineScript{Invoke-Command -ComputerName $using:server -Credential $using:credential -Filepath C:\Checkhost.ps1}
        inlineScript {Exit-PSSession}
        inlineScript{Remove-PSSession -id $using:id}
    }
}
```

See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-workflows-restrictions/) for the restrictions in Workflow

Comment: @pirasoon, I'm unable to execute the above code. it throws error "Unable to find type [PSCrdential]". if possible post the code.

Comment: That was a typo and corrected it now. You could have searched with the error as well.

Comment: the credentials working.. i have assigned a variable to invoke-command ps1 file to return something. but it doesnt return anything. Can hep?   $value = inlineScript{Invoke-Command -ComputerName $using:server -Credential $using:credential -Filepath C:\Checkhost.ps1} $vaule